# if else statement within foreach causes error

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a php function used to update/add discount pricing to products in bulk.

The code worked perfectly until <strike>I added the additional $new_price conditions & substr check on the sku</strike>
I added the p.sku in the select statement. It now gives me a blank screen and the query is not run when I try to execute it.

```
if ($user_group == 15 && $percent == 0) {
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount WHERE customer_group_id = '".$user_group."' AND quantity = '".$quantity."'");

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT p.product_id, p.sku, p.cost, p.price FROM product p");

    foreach ($query->rows as $result) {

        if ((substr($result['sku'],0,3) == 'ACA')) {
        $new_price = ($result['cost'] * 32.5 / 100 + $result['cost']);
        } else {
        $new_price = ($result['cost'] * 40 / 100 + $result['cost']);
        }

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount SET 
        `product_id` = '" . $result['product_id'] . "', 
        `customer_group_id` = '15',
        `quantity` = '".$quantity."',
        `priority` = '".$priority."',
        `price` = '".$new_price."',
        `date_start` = '".$start_date."',
        `date_end` = '".$expire_date."'");
    }

}
```

What am I missing here? I've been searching the forum & google etc and trying various things all afternoon and i'm fed up! Please help anyone!

After adding error reporting to the index.php I finally got a clue:
**"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)"**

Here is the full code for the function with some minor changes based on the comments, I have no idea why all memory is used up hopefully someone can help:

```
<?php
    class ModelBulkDiscount extends Model {

    public function updateDiscount($user_group = null, $percent = 0, $quantity = 1, $priority = 0, $start_date = null, $expire_date = null) {

if($user_group != 15 && $percent > 0) {
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount WHERE customer_group_id = '".$user_group."' AND quantity = '".$quantity."'");

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT p.product_id, p.price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p");

    foreach ($query->rows as $result) {

        $new_price = $result['price'] - (($result['price'] / 100) * $percent);

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount SET 
        `product_id` = '" . $result['product_id'] . "', 
        `customer_group_id` = '" . $user_group . "',
        `quantity` = '".$quantity."',
        `priority` = '".$priority."',
        `price` = '".$new_price."',
        `date_start` = '".$start_date."',
        `date_end` = '".$expire_date."'");

    }

} else if ($user_group == 15 && $percent == 0) {
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount WHERE customer_group_id = '".$user_group."' AND quantity = '".$quantity."'");

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT p.product_id, p.sku, p.cost, p.price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p");

    foreach ($query->rows as $result) {

    if ((substr($result['sku'],0,3) == 'ACA')) {
        $new_price = ($result['cost'] * 1.325);
    } else {
        $new_price = ($result['cost'] * 1.4);
    }

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount SET 
        `product_id` = '" . $result['product_id'] . "', 
        `customer_group_id` = '15',
        `quantity` = '".$quantity."',
        `priority` = '".$priority."',
        `price` = '".$new_price."',
        `date_start` = '".$start_date."',
        `date_end` = '".$expire_date."'");
    }

} else if ($user_group == 15 && $percent > 0) {
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount WHERE customer_group_id = '".$user_group."' AND quantity = '".$quantity."'");

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT p.product_id, p.cost, p.price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p");

    foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
        $temp_price = ($result['cost'] * 1.325);
        $new_price = $temp_price - (($temp_price / 100) * $percent);

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount SET 
        `product_id` = '" . $result['product_id'] . "', 
        `customer_group_id` = '15',
        `quantity` = '".$quantity."',
        `priority` = '".$priority."',
        `price` = '".$new_price."',
        `date_start` = '".$start_date."',
        `date_end` = '".$expire_date."'");
    }
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Turn error reporting on.

Comment: blank screen = something blew up, and you've got error reporting/display turned off. turn them on, and check the server logs. You could simplify the math as simply `$new_price = $result['cost'] * 1.4` or `* 1.325` as well.

Comment: Are you sure that $user_group is equal to 15 and that $percent is zero?  Can you put a echo hello in there to make sure the if condition is true.

Comment: Check your php error logn there should be the error in it

Comment: error reporting on but no errors reported, error logs show the same. 100% Positive that $user_group is equal to 15 and that percent is zero. Just noticed that the blank screen only happens when I add the p.sku in the select statement!?

Comment: This link has always worked for me with the white screen. http://drupal.org/node/158043

Comment: add print_r($result) in the foreeach, turn error reporting on.

Comment: If you're using old `mysql_*`, try to get error report by `mysql_error()` otherwise, if you're with PDO or something like that try to get it by `PDO::errorInfo()`. SQL errors wouldn't show up like PHP triggered errors. And if this is a framework like CI, try to `var_dump()` the `$query` too see whether it's running or not.

Comment: Thanks Eoin Murphy - added the code to my index.php and it now shows an error that it didnt before"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)" How do I get around this! Never seen this before

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can imagine from looking at your code might be that the initial SQL query returns a dataset which exceeds PHP's memory limits. Maybe you could try adding a `LIMIT 100` or similar to the query, and see if the problem persists. You could also look for a way to get the table's size in bytes from the DB server, and see if it exceeds 128MB.

On another note: Processing a large number of records in PHP is not the best approach performance-wise, since the whole data has to be transferred from the SQL server to the PHP interpreter process and then transferred back. The code you posted looks like something you would typically implement directly in the data base with a special query (maybe even using stored procedures).

Essentially, you're trying to insert a large number of records based on data from another table. So you want to perform a select on that table and use it as a subexpression for your insert. Have a look at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

I don't consider myself an SQL expert, but to give you an idea how this might work, just for a subset of the fields:

```
INSERT INTO product_discount (product_id, customer_product_id, new_price) SELECT 
sub.product_id, 15, sub.new_price FROM (
    SELECT p.product_id, p.price*1.35 AS new_price FROM products
) AS sub;
```

**Note:** I've left out part of the new_price calculation, since it would have required another sub-SELECT, and I wanted to preserve readability. But it is also possible using pure SQL. It's not as intuitive as imperative programming, but SQL offers a lot of functionality, and stuff like conditional expressions are also possible.

You should be able to formulate a query which performs the desired operation entirely in the DB. That way, there is no need to transfer any data between DB and PHP, which will very likely be much faster, and you won't run out of memory.